# Digital ocean kubernetes cluster connection error

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-cluster

I have created kubernetes cluster on digital ocean having 1 worker node and one master node.

As per digital ocean guide line i followed step and download kubernetes cluster config file

```
kubectl --kubeconfig="filename.yaml" get nodes
```

but it is showing

```
Unable to connect to the server: unexpected EOF
```

While Kubernetes cluster is Up and Running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i have blinding fire cluster more thn 10-11 time with different configuration and in different region etc.

after leaving company place i again tried it from home network and in first time it's work so well.

```
SO In my case it was Network provider problem blocking port and connection request
```

Also suggest you to check network issue first and own network configuration

Comment: I had the same issue ... disconnected from company network and used my mobile tethering ... and it worked perfectly ..

Comment: i think digital ocean system is not mature that much still some time it work or some time not work

Comment: @HarshManvar Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are using right config yaml file otherwise try to destroy and create fresh Kubernetes cluster on Digital Ocean and try again. It should work properly

Comment: i tried a lot many time & using right config file still it is not working. tried 6-7 time but not working