# digital ocean k8s cluster connection issue x509

Tags: kubernetes

As per digital ocean guide line i followed step and download kubernetes cluster config file

```
kubectl --kubeconfig="filename.yaml" get nodes
but it is showing
```

Unable to connect to the server: unexpected EOF
While Kubernetes cluster is Up and Running

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090438/digital-ocean-kubernetes-cluster-connection-error duplicate question i think check it answer again.

Answer (score 0):

tried with changing connection if possible with mobile network or with other network and test it once over other network.

sometime having problem to make connection with digital ocean

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. Make sure you are using the correct configuration file.
2. Make sure 8001 is accessible to connect with the kubernetes api server.